# Generate Buttons for 'Future' hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate multi-select buttons for each future hour of the day until 9 PM and displayed in 30 minute increments. For example, if it is 4:45 PM for the user, the user should see a list of buttons for:
5:00 PM, 5:30 PM, 6:00 PM, 6:30 PM, 7:00 PM, 7:30 PM... until 9PM.

So in 12-hour format rather than 24-hour. This is used in a form for when a customer would like a service delivered. They should be able to select as many options from these buttons.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const timeOptions = [
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    8,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
  ]

let now = new Date();
let currentHour = now.getHours();
let currentMinute = now.getMinutes();
let availableTimes = [];

for (const time of timeOptions) {
  if (time > currentHour) {
    availableTimes.push(time);
  }
}

$('#repairFormContainer').append('<div id="time-choices"></div>');

let count = 0;
for (const time of availableTimes) {
  if (count === 0 || time === 13) {
    count += 1;
    createTimeButtonGroup();
  }
  $('#time-choices-group').append(
    `
      <label class="time-button btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" id=${time}>${time}
      </label>
      <label class="time-button btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" id="${time}:30">${time}:30
      </label>
    `
  )
}

const createTimeButtonGroup = () => {
  $('#time-choices').append('<div id="time-choices-group" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" 
  data-toggle="buttons"></div>')
}
```

I'm separating the groups of times with the idea of making the AM buttons one column and the PM buttons another column, but that's for a later point I guess. I feel like I'm going in the wrong direction. I'm unsure of how to get the 30 minute increments to work while also displaying in 12-hour format. I obviously can't do what I'm currently doing (just appending `:30` to the end of the time) - I need it to go form 12:30 to 1 PM rather than 13.. Any ideas? Also, the idea behind the `time === 13` was to switch to using a different list of times to handle 13, 14, etc.. But I'm not sure how to do that exactly. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Add function `getTimeString` and use it as `getTimeString(time, '')` & `getTimeString(time, ':30')`.

You can check below.

```js
const timeOptions = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
  
const createTimeButtonGroup = () => {
  $('#time-choices').append('<div id="time-choices-group" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons"></div>')
}

const getTimeString = (time, minutes) => {
  if(time >= 13) {
    return `${time%12}${minutes} PM`
  } else if (time == 12){
    return `12${minutes} PM`
  }
  return `${time}${minutes} AM`
}

let now = new Date();
let currentHour = now.getHours();
let currentMinute = now.getMinutes();
let availableTimes = [];

for (const time of timeOptions) {
  if (time > currentHour) {
    availableTimes.push(time);
  }
}

$('#repairFormContainer').append('<div id="time-choices"></div>');

let count = 0;
for (const time of availableTimes) {
  if (count === 0 || time === 13) {
    count += 1;
    createTimeButtonGroup();
  }
  $('#time-choices-group').append(
    `
      <label class="time-button btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" id=${time}>${getTimeString(time, '')}
      </label>
      <label class="time-button btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" id="${time}:30">${getTimeString(time, ':30')}
      </label>
    `
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="repairFormContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Wow you're amazing. Thank you!